# How to pass parameters to subreports?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I have 5 reports that all have 2 parameters: startdate and enddate.

```
select *  from table where date between startdate and enddate
```

This is a simplified version of what I have, but for this problem, it should work.

I need to have all of the tables in 1 compiled report and link all of their parameters. I think I might be approaching this problem incorrectly. First of all, the server that I'm publishing the report to is SQL Server 2008, not SQL Server 2008 R2, so I don't think I can use report parts (correct me if I'm wrong). Because of this, I thought that the best way to approach this would be to use subreports. I created a new report that will contain the other reports as subreports. In the subreport properties, I set startdate equal to:

```
=Parameters!startdate.Value
```

Startdate exists in the new final report and it has a default value. I did the same thing with enddate. However, when I run it, I get the error "One or more parameters were not specified for the subreport, 'Subreport', located at :/Subreport."

I'd really appreciate any help with this, and I apologize for the length of this post. I tried to find this online, but I couldn't, so I finally made an account so that I could ask this question.

Edit: I never found the solution to this problem, but I achieved the result I wanted by just copy and pasting the tables and adding the respective datasets to the main report.

Comment: Are you sending startdate and enddate into all SubReports?

Comment: Um, I'm not sure. All I did was add parameters in the subreport properties. Is "sending" something else?

Comment: Added a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to define startDate and endDate in your main report as well as all reports that will be used as a SubReport. I don't think you are mapping the paremeters. SSRS will not auto-map same named parameters.

1. Add a SubReport component from the toolbox onto your main report
2. Right click on the SubReport and select sub-report properties
3. Select the Parameters list view item from the left hand list view
   NOTE : If the SubReport is contained in the same vs project as your main report you should see the available SubReport parameters.
4. Map the name of the SubReport parameter to the value of your main report's associated parameter.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, and that's what I tried to do. I made a short image album with captions to describe what I did: [http://imgur.com/a/2zZda#0](http://imgur.com/a/2zZda#0)

Comment: Take a look at this article http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f49d6762-199d-45f8-a946-a5fda47ac056/one-or-more-parameters-were-not-specified-for-the-subreport?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: I looked at that, and other similar articles, very closely, but I couldn't find my problem. I ended up just using multiple tables and adding the datasets to the main report...I think I'm just sleep deprived or something. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Stumbled on this answer while looking for a solution - for the benefit of others who might be reading this I found the parameters added to subreport properties (I had nothing in the drop-down either) had to be entered with the same case (as in upper/lower case) as they are within the subreport.